A hexadecimal number consists of the digits {0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F}. How many 5 digit hexadecimal numbers have exactly two letters?
Note: a hexadecimal number will not start with 0.
The answer is 338,400.
This question requires counting techniques (multi set, combination, permutation, product rule, etc.) to solve. The closest answer I've come up with is 332,700.
5C2 (choose 2 spot from 5 for the 2 letters).
6² (A,B,C,D,E,F, 6 choices for the 2 spots).
10³ (0-9 10 choices for 3 spots left).
5C2 × 6² × 10³ = 10 × 36 × 1000 = 360,000.
Then I subtracted 15 × 16⁴ = 27,300.
360,000 - 27,300 = 332,700.
I'm kind of just confused on all the different techniques and how to apply them. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thxxx

What is the probability of a number being letter in base $16$? What is the probability of exactly $2$ number out of $5$ number is letter in base $16$? What is the probability of the first number is $0$?

What have you tried? It's easier for others to help you when you provide some hint about where you are getting stuck.

I will start by splitting this into 2 cases. The first is where the first digit is a letter and the second is where the first digit is not a letter (but as you stated, not 0). In the first case, there is $(^4_1) = 4$ possibilities to put the second letter. There are 6 possibilities for each of the letter digits and 10 possibilities for each of the 3 non-letter digits. This gives us there are $4*6^2*10^3$ possibilities for this case. For the second case. There are $(^4_2) = 6$ possibilities to put the letters. Then, again, we have that each letter digit has 6 choices and the 2 non-leading numerical digits have 10 possibilities. However, the leading digit cannot be a 0 so it only has 9 choices. This gives us $6*6^2*10^2*9$ possibilities for the second case. Add these together and you get the 338,400 that you give in the question!
I'm not sure how you got $15*16^4 = 27,300$ but that would have subtracted all the possible 5 digit numbers that don't start with 0. Instead of this you have to subtract all the numbers that you counted in your 360,000 count that were not supposed to be counted. These numbers are the ones that start with zero and still have exactly two digits. When you count this number of possibilities you get $(^4_2)*10^2*6^2 = 21,600$. We can then see $360,000 - 21,600$ gives the right answer.
